when i run my project it seems everything right but nothing show in Android studio virtual device
when I run my project in vs code by write in the terminal flutter run it seems everything right but nothing show in Android studio virtual device
I tried too much like write in the terminal flutter clean , flutter pub get ,cd android ./gradlew clean , ./gradlew build and other things even when I put Chrome still nothing show up.
enter image description here
I added my project to firebase maybe I did not added it correct or no I don't know.

There is Flutter plugin in android studio did you tried to install it?

Yes I tried it too
